# Swift Codable not working for array of values

Tags: ios, swift

In my case I am trying to get `JSON` data using codable. Here, I can’t able to get `data[Datum]` values. How to get it and assign tableview data. I used to generate codable by using `quicktype.io`

- JSON Data

```
 {
     "status": true,
     "data": [
         {
             "id": "1",
             "name": "one",
             "description": "hello",
             "date": "2020-08-05 11:37:52",
             "startdate": "2019-08-05 11:37:52",
             "createdby": "1",
             "status": "0"
         },
         {
             "id": "2",
             "name": "two",
             "description": "hi",
             "date": "2020-08-05 11:37:52",
             "startdate": "2019-08-05 11:37:52",
             "createdby": "1",
             "status": "0"
         }
     ]
 }
```

- Codable Struct

```
 // MARK: - Welcome
 struct Welcome: Codable {
     let status: Bool
     let data: [Datum]
 }

     // MARK: - Datum
     struct Datum: Codable {
         let id, name, datumDescription, date: String
         let startdate, createdby, status: String

         enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
             case id, name
             case datumDescription = "description"
             case date, startdate, createdby, status
         }
     }
```

- Code

```
 let id: String = result.data.(Nothing Showing except Description)
```

Comment: And where is your code for doing the actual decoding? Do you get an error, if so please add the error message to your question

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I can't get array of data from codable? how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

```
let id: String = result.data.(Nothing Showing except Description)
```

It's not clear what "Nothing Showing except Description" means here, but the syntax you would expect would be:

```
let id: String = result.data[0].id   // The id of the first Datum
```

`data` is an Array, so you'll need to subscript or iterate over it to get elements. For a tableview, you'd expect something like:

```
let id: String = result.data[indexPath.row].id
```

If this is not what you mean, you need to edit your question to make clear what your actual code is and the specific error message you receive.